# How to stop a java swing timer

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, timer, runnable

This application has 2 threads the one shown here calls a method that pauses an auto clicker method every 4 seconds(just for ease) to do some mouse movement. I want it to stop the timer when you click the gui stop button.
Right now when you hit stop and then start again it then has two timers that will execute the code; and so on.

Action Listener Stuff.

```
class MyButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource().equals(view.getBtnStart()))
        {
            autoClick.unTerminate();
            bool = true;
            getInfo();
        }
        if (e.getSource().equals(view.getBtnExit()))
        { 
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if (e.getSource().equals(view.getBtnStop()))
        {
            bool = false;
            autoClick.terminate();
        }
    }//end of actionPerformed
}//end of inner class
```

Thread

```
Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Timer timer = new Timer(4000, new ActionListener() {//301000 5minutes and 1second
                            @Override
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                                autoClick.timeOverload();
                            }                                
                        });
                        //if (!bool){timer.stop();}
                        timer.setRepeats(true); //false only repeates once
                        timer.start();
                    }
                    });//end of t2
```

It calls the timeOverload method repeatedly.

Thanks for your time and helping a newbie out :).

Comment: If you build your timer outside of the thread  `final` to be able to [`stop`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#stop()) him, this will do it. Or you can use a `boolean` to check on each tick if it needs to `stop` itself

Comment: @AxelH I tried what I 'thought' you meant but i didn't seem to find the right way to do it. If you wouldn't mind an example would be great.

Comment: I could, but I need a [mcve] for that. Could you provide an example using only a Thread and Timer, no GUI or `autoClick` instance ?

Comment: What your looking for I think is something like this: `if (!bool) { ((Timer)evt.getSource()).stop(); }`

Comment: @DevilsHnd, that was the seconds solution I had in mind, you could post an answer based on that (you are welcome to use the sample I have used in my answer)

Comment: Uhhh...Looks like you've provided a good enough example @AxelH for this OP to get the jest of things however he/she will perhaps still need to consider the concept of thread locking and Thread.interrupt()  ;)

Comment: @DevilsHnd You can provide your answer, I would only keep my first solution since this is your code also ;)

Comment: Nonsense @AxelH....it's everyone's code. :) Thank you. I had already given my solution my friend, it's up to the OP to research a little further to grasp the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick sample of how to declare a instance outside of your thread and be able to control it outside of it.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    final Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("tick");
        }
    });
    timer.setRepeats(true);

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            timer.start();
        }
    });
    t.start();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2600);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    timer.stop();
}
```

Basicly, you need to set the instance `final` to be used in a anonymous class (the ActionListener implementation).

Here, I just start the thread then pause the process for a few seconds and stop the timer.

Note that here, the Thread don't do anything else so it ends directly. You will need to tweek this a bit to match your needs but you have a working example.

EDIT : (DevilsHnd, if you post your answer, notify me, I will remove this part)

Using a flag (here in a Class)

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Main();
    }

    boolean running = true;

    public Main(){
        final Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(!running){
                    ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("tick");
                }
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2600);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        stop();
    }

    public void stop(){
        running = false;
    }
}
```

Calling the `Main.stop()` will set the flag to false, on each action performed, you check this flag, if it is false, you get the timer from the event (in the source) and stop it.

Comment: Sorry for the hassle but I have what's there. But say I want to stop the timer when a variable (bool) switches to false. I've been trying to put an if around the System.out.println inside the actionPerformed to test if bool was true and if not stop timer.

Comment: @Hades, well, precise this next time, this is not in your question. But I have edited my answer to use this solution.